# Outlook scan specific folder and save all attachments from e-mails

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code to save attachments for selected items(mails) from my Outlook.

I would like to set the specific folder (define it) and Outlook will automatically scan all e-mails in that folder and save attachments.

Any ideas how should I expand this code to work that way?

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

strFolderpath = "C:\Users\gpyko\Desktop\Pentaho project\HDPS RAPORTY"
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"

For Each objMsg In objSelection

  Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
  lngCount = objAttachments.Count
  strDeletedFiles = ""

  If lngCount > 0 Then

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

      strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
      strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
      objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
      objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

      If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then

            strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
      Else
            strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
            strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
      End If

    Next i

      If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then

          objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
      Else
          objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
      End If
      objMsg.Save

  End If

Next

ExitSub:
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Excel or Outlook ?

Comment: From Outlook right now, but probably I'll run it from Excel combined with other VBA script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your objSelection with `Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder` then use 
`For Each objMsg In SubFolder.Items`

also you don't need to create Outlook object if your running your code from Outlook `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

Make sure to update your folder name

`Set SubFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder Name")`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    strFolderpath = "C:\Users\gpyko\Desktop\Pentaho project\HDPS RAPORTY"

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set SubFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder Name")

    strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"


    For Each objMsg In SubFolder.Items
        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        strDeletedFiles = ""

        If lngCount > 0 Then

            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then

                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            Next i

            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then

                objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
            Else
                objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
            End If

            objMsg.Save

        End If
    Next


ExitSub:
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

To Run it from Excel.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim App As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    strFolderpath = "C:\Users\gpyko\Desktop\Pentaho project\HDPS RAPORTY"
    Set App = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set SubFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder Name")

    strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"


    For Each objMsg In SubFolder.Items
        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        strDeletedFiles = ""

        If lngCount > 0 Then

            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).Filename
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
            objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then

                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            Next i

            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then

                objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
            Else
                objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
            End If

            objMsg.Save

        End If
    Next

ExitSub:
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciate. Yet I still face up an error on line:
 `Set SubFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ARIES")`
"An object could not be found". Folder name is correct. Maybe i miss something?

Comment: @GrzegorzPyko an object could not be found means your folder name cannot be found.

Comment: yea, but I'm sure that folder name is correct and I have one named that way

Comment: Ok I know where the problem is. The folder I want to scan is at the same rank as Inbox, Drafts, Sent Items etc. So the function and argument `.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` won't work.

Comment: You could use `Set SubFolder = olNS.PickFolder` to bring up the Select Folder dialog.

Comment: Ok I got it. I used `Set SubFolder = olNs.Folders("mailbox-name").Folders("ARIES")` and it works.
One more time big thank you!