# Using a hyperlink to link to a document in an outlook mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I was trying to use the following code to insert a "Click here" link to link to the document that is open but I am having an issue.

When the email has been drafted and the link is inserted, only some of the hyperlink is carried over to the email, meaning that the hyperlink does not work.

I am trying the following to do this:

```
Private Sub Completion_Notification()

Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object
Dim Strbody As String
Dim CommentsPath As String
Dim CommentsName As String

CommentsName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
CommentsPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

Strbody = "<A href=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ">Click Here</A>"

'Getting the email List
Dim i As Integer
Dim Email_Rng As Range
Dim Num_of_Emails As Integer

         
            Dim OutApp As Object
            Dim OutMail As Object
            
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
                With OutMail
                
                .To = "Email"
                .CC = ""
                .Subject = "Email_Subject"
                .HTMLBody = "<html><p>Hi, " & "</p>" & _
                 "<p>" & Strbody & _
                "<p>" & "Many Thanks"

                    .Display
                    '.Send
        
                End With
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, when I step into the code and check the value for the "strbody" expression the link is there in full so I have no idea why this would not be working. is there a Limit to the number of characters that can be inserted into the href?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424880/4539709

Comment: It doesn't make sense to reference local files without attaching them to the mail item. The recipient will not be able to open or load such files on the remote machine.

Comment: the file is located on a shared local server so everyone who has access to the server can access the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To represent a link to a local file, Use **`<A HREF=""file://`***

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub example()

    Dim Strbody As String
        Strbody = "<A HREF=""file://" & _
                    Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
                    """>Click Here</A>"
    
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>Hi, " & "</p>" & _
        "<p>" & Strbody & _
        "<p>" & "Many Thanks"
        
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: this works when I manually put the server name in but if the server name were to change this method would not work, however, for the purposes of what I am doing it works great, thanks!